# How to use Drupal 6 views and panels arguments together?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-views

I need to acheive the following layout/setup for a section of my website:

Using the following panels layout:

**Top column spanning full width** containing:
- a view (prob themed using jquery cycle) of images relating to current node

**3 columns below** containing:

1. Left column: List of 4 single hierarchy taxonomy terms:

   - Term 1
   - Term 2 (selected)
   - Term 3
   - Term 4
2. Middle column: List view of node titles tagged with taxonomy term selected in left column

   - Node1 title (tagged with term 2) (selected)
   - Node2 title (tagged with term 2)
   - etc.
3. Right column: Contents of node selected in middle column

   - Node 1

I'm a newbie. I think in theory I can do this with just views and panels, passing the term id and node id as arguments.  But I need someone to point me in the right direction because I don't know how to make the views and panels arguments and contexts work together. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You're probably better off ditching panels and just making a block yourself to display the top panel.  The [Acquia Marina theme](http://drupal.org/project/acquia_marina) has a layout that lets you have this exact setup - a block above your content but below the header, with up to 3 columns underneath that. Just go ahead and copy their layout code from a finished page to get the effect you're looking for without having to use the panels module at all.

Answer (score 0):

For the top column, you can use the Views Slideshow module. You should find it pretty straightforward. In the Views style settings, simply select Slideshow, then you can modify the default settings to achieve the effect you want.

THe next issue will depend on how you implement your taxonomy. Practically, I find that using term ID as an argument is the most straightforward approach and I usually don't find the need to set a specific validation.

When your Views are created with the necessary arguments, you will need to define how they will be retrieved.

Panels gives you the possibility to select the various parts of the URL and define what type of taxonomy ( for instance ) they are, so that you can then pass these to the Views.

In the Basic settings of the Panel, create your path by using placeholders which will represent your taxonomy terms.

```
for instance:
example.com/content/%term1/%term3/%term4
```

And in the Context pane, define your terms and select which Vocabulary they belong to.

Now when adding a View to the Panel, in the Settings pane you should find a menu allowing you to select the term needed by the View.